SNMP doesn't seem to register pass-through configuration directive
SNMP doesn't seem to register pass-through configuration directive, here is my configuration file:
snmpd.conf
###########################################################################
#
# snmpd.conf An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP agent ('snmpd') See snmpd.conf(5) man
# page for details
#
###########################################################################
# SECTION: System Information Setup
#

# syslocation: The [typically physical] location of the system.
#   Note that setting this value here means that when trying to
#   perform an snmp SET operation to the sysLocation.0 variable will make
#   the agent return the "notWritable" error code.  IE, including
#   this token in the snmpd.conf file will disable write access to
#   the variable.
#   arguments:  location_string
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>

# sysservices: The proper value for the sysServices object.
#   arguments:  sysservices_number
sysServices    72



###########################################################################
# SECTION: Agent Operating Mode
#
#   This section defines how the agent will operate when it
#   is running.

# master: Should the agent operate as a master agent or not.
#   Currently, the only supported master agent type for this token
#   is "agentx".
#
#   arguments: (on|yes|agentx|all|off|no)

master  agentx

# agentaddress: The IP address and port number that the agent will listen on.
#   By default the agent listens to any and all traffic from any
#   interface on the default SNMP port (161).  This allows you to
#   specify which address, interface, transport type and port(s) that you
#   want the agent to listen on.  Multiple definitions of this token
#   are concatenated together (using ':'s).
#   arguments: [transport:]port[@interface/address],...

agentaddress  161



###########################################################################
# SECTION: Access Control Setup
#
#   This section defines who is allowed to talk to your running
#   snmp agent.

# Views
#   arguments viewname included [oid]

#  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1


# rocommunity: a SNMPv1/SNMPv2c read-only access community name
#   arguments:  community [default|hostname|network/bits] [oid | -V view]

# Read-only access to everyone to the systemonly view
rocommunity public
#rocommunity  public default -V systemonly
#rocommunity6 public default -V systemonly

#rocommunity public localhost
#view all included .1.3.6.1.4.1

#extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.9999.1 checkcommand /bin/sh /home/pi/snmp/snmp-cpu-temp

# SNMPv3 doesn't use communities, but users with (optionally) an
# authentication and encryption string. This user needs to be created
# with what they can view with rouser/rwuser lines in this file.
#
# createUser username (MD5|SHA|SHA-512|SHA-384|SHA-256|SHA-224) authpassphrase [DES|AES] [privpassphrase]
# e.g.
# createuser authPrivUser SHA-512 myauthphrase AES myprivphrase
#
# This should be put into /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf
#
# rouser: a SNMPv3 read-only access username
#    arguments: username [noauth|auth|priv [OID | -V VIEW [CONTEXT]]]
#rouser authPrivUser authpriv -V systemonly
#rouser authOnlyUser

#
# Process Monitoring
#
# At least one 'mountd' process
proc mountd
# No more than 4 'ntalkd' processes - 0 is OK
proc ntalkd 4
# At least one 'sendmail' process, but no more than 10
proc sendmail 10 1

# Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable to see the resulting output
# Note that this table will be empty if there are no "proc" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
# Disk Monitoring
#
# 10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
disk / 10000
disk /var 5%
includeAllDisks 10%

# Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskTable to see the resulting output
# Note that this table will be empty if there are no "disk" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
# System Load
#
# Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages
load 12 10 5

# Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::laTable to see the resulting output
# Note that this table *will* be populated, even without a "load" entry in the snmpd.conf file



###############################################################################
#
# ACTIVE MONITORING
#

# send SNMPv1 traps
trapsink localhost public
# send SNMPv2c traps
#trap2sink localhost public
# send SNMPv2c INFORMs
#informsink localhost public

# Note that you typically only want *one* of these three lines
# Uncommenting two (or all three) will result in multiple copies of each notification.


#
# Event MIB - automatically generate alerts
#
# Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
iquerySecName internalUser
rouser internalUser
# generate traps on UCD error conditions
#defaultMonitors yes
# generate traps on linkUp/Down
linkUpDownNotifications yes



###############################################################################
#
# EXTENDING THE AGENT
#

#
# Arbitrary extension commands
#
extend test1 /bin/echo Hello, world!
extend-sh test2 echo Hello, world! ; echo Hi there ; exit 35

pass .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8 /bin/sh /home/pi/snmp/snmp-cpu-temp

# include a all *.conf files in a directory
includeDir /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.d

/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.d is empty, I've restarted the snmpd service.
$ snmpget -v 2c localhost -c public .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8
iso.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID

$ sh /home/pi/snmp/snmp-cpu-temp -g .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8
.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8
gauge
62322


If you run sh /home/pi/snmp/snmp-cpu-temp -g .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8, it should output exactly three lines: the first line should be the OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8, the second should be the type of the returned value, and the third line should be the actual value. If the snmp-cpu-temp script runs without producing such an output, you'll get the No Such Instance currently exists at this OID error.

It does output those three lines, I've added the output to the question body.

Does this system have SELinux or AppArmor? If so, there might be rules in place to prevent daemons like snmpd from executing stuff in users' home directories.
Try placing your script to /usr/local/bin/snmp-cpu-temp instead and mark it as executable:
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/snmp-cpu-temp

Then change your pass line in snmpd.conf to:
pass .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.8 /usr/local/bin/snmp-cpu-temp

